# How to filter object in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, lambda

Let's say I have a class:

```
class Cell {
  int ID;
  int valueX;
  int valueY;
};
```

and in main() I declared vector of Cells:

```
vector<Cell> myCells;
```

My problem is to write a function that gets vector of Cells, operator (gt - greater than, le - less or equal, and so on), name of a variable and an integer, and returns vector of Cells that meets the requirement?
For example:

```
vector<Cells> resultCells = filter(myCells, gt, valueX, 5)
```

is vector of Cells where each cell has valueX greater than 5.

My first attempts required a lot of ifs and switches and I'm sure it's not proper solution.
Then I asked a friend for a tip, he told me about things like functors, lambdas, std::function, std::map, std::bind, that can help me to do this and I've read about it but I am unable to use in in practise.

One of examples that I've seen on the Internet is [*this*](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html) one, but it's less complex and hard to reuse (for me).

Comment: Please show us a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. (And remember minimal AND complete).

Comment: Do you have C++14?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
for (auto& c : myCells)
    if (c.valueX > 5)
        resultCells.push_back(c);
```

---

For your specific requirement (*"write a function that gets vector of Cells, operator (gt - greater than, le - less or equal, and so on), name of a variable and an integer, and returns vector of Cells"*), assuming "get" means "take as parameter":

```
vector<Cell> filter(vector<Cell> const& cells,
                    function<bool(int,int)> const& op,
                    int Cell::* var,
                    int i) {
    vector<Cell> results;
    for (auto& c : cells)
        if (op(c.*var, i))
            results.push_back(c);
    return results;
}
```

Usage:

```
resultCells = filter(myCells, greater<int>(),  &Cell::valueX, 5);
resultCells = filter(myCells, less<int>(),     &Cell::valueY, 5);
resultCells = filter(myCells, equal_to<int>(), &Cell::ID,     5);
```

Answer (score 15):

Try something like this using [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) :

```
std::vector<Cell> resultCells;
std::copy_if(myCells.begin(), myCells.end(),
             std::back_inserter(resultCells),
             [](const Cell& c) { return c.valueX > 5; });
```

Comment: I really wish the answer using `<algorithm>` would've been checkmarked as "the" answer.

Answer (score 1):

In C++14:

```
template<class T, class A, class F>
std::vector<T,A> keep_only( std::vector<T,A> input, F&& filter ) {
  auto it = std::remove_if( begin(input), end(input), [&](T const& t)->bool {
    return !filter(t);
  });
  input.erase(it, end(input));
  return input;
}

auto v2 = keep_only(v1, [](auto&& x){return x.valueX>5;}
```

in C++11 replace `auto&&` with `Cell const&`.

This version modifies a copy of the vector it takes.  This means it copies every element, then discards some, and in that discarding moves elements.  This is more optimal in the case where you are already getting the incoming vector via copy, as it can be elided/moved into.  If your objects are expensive to copy and you throw away most of them, this isn't optimal.

---

We can make `keep_only` not be restricted to input vectors via:

```
namespace details {
  template<class C, class F>
  auto keep_only( C&& input, F&& filter ) {
    using std::begin; using std::end;
    using T = std::decay_t<decltype(*begin(input))>;

    std::vector<T> retval;
    std::copy_if(
      begin(input), end(input),
      std::back_inserter(retval),
      std::forward<F>(filter)
    );
    return retval;
  }
}
template<class C, class F>
auto keep_only( C&& input, F&& filter ) {
  return details::keep_only(std::forward<C>(input), std::forward<F>(filter));
}
```

and add initializer list support:

```
template<class T, class F>
std::vector<T> keep_only( std::initializer_list<T> input, F&& filter ) {
  return details::keep_only(input, std::forward<F>(filter));
}
```

so you can type `keep_only( {1,2,3,4,5,6}, [](int x){return x>1;} )`

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b28e717d1b56a9a0)

This version only copies the ones you tell it to keep.  It also moves the elements you keep on average once during vector resizing.  Regardless of the input, it always returns a vector.  Writing this in C++11 is probably not worth it, because properly deducing `T` takes a bit of boilerplate outside of the function context.

You can get the best of both worlds by taking the first implementation, and changing the signature to:

```
template<class T, class A, class F>
std::vector<T,A> keep_only( std::vector<T,A>&& input, F&& filter ) {
```

and making the return be `return std::move(input);`: now, for anything except for a temporary vector, we construct a vector and copy stuff into it.  For a temporary vector, we instead filter the parts we don't want out of it.

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way to do this, depending on whether you want to keep the original vector or not.

In your example, one form would be to use [copy_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy_if/) to  transfer the elements from myCells to resultCells. This may be expensive if you have a big container and don't need to use myCells afterwards. In that case, it would be better to use [remove_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/) on myCells itself.

A third option would be to use [remove_copy_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_copy_if/) to remove from myCells while simultaneously adding to resultCells.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the OP's requirement explicitly, here is the required signature:

`vector<Cells> resultCells = filter(myCells, gt, valueX, 5)`

And here is how it's achieved:

```
template<class T, class Pred, class ValueType>
std::vector<T> filter(std::vector<T> result, Pred pred, ValueType T::* member, ValueType model)
{
    result.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(result),
                                std::end(result),
                                [&] (const auto& elem) {
                                    !return pred(elem.*member, model);
                                }),
                 std::end(result));
    return result;
}
```

Full working example (c++14 - c++11 will require a little more plumbing):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

struct Cell {
    int ID;
    int valueX;
    int valueY;
};

template<class T, class Pred, class ValueType>
std::vector<T> filter(std::vector<T> result, Pred pred, ValueType T::* member, ValueType model)
{
    result.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(result),
                                std::end(result),
                                [&] (const auto& elem) {
                                    return !pred(elem.*member, model);
                                }),
                 std::end(result));
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    auto myCells = std::vector<Cell> {
        { 0, 1, 2 },
        { 1, 2, 2 },
        { 2, 4, 2 },
        { 3, 6, 2 }
    };
    auto resultCells = filter(myCells, std::greater<>(), &Cell::valueX, 5);
    std::cout << resultCells.size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
1
```